# What is the difference between geoms and stats in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Both geoms and stats can be used to make plots in the R package ggplot2, and they often give similar results (e.g., geom_area and stat_bin). They also often have slightly different arguments, e.g. in [2-D density plots](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_density_2d.html):

```
geom_density_2d(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "density2d",
  position = "identity", ..., lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round",
  linemitre = 1, na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE)

stat_density_2d(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "density_2d",
  position = "identity", ..., contour = TRUE, n = 100, h = NULL, na.rm =
  FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE)
```

Are there any fundamental differences between the two types of objects?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

geoms stand for "geometric objects." These are the core elements that you see on the plot, object like points, lines, areas, curves.

stats stand for "statistical transformations." These objects summarize the data in different ways such as counting observations, creating a loess line that best fits the data, or adding a confidence interval to the loess line.

As geoms are the "core" of the plot, these are required objects. On the other hand, stats are not required to produce a plot, but can greatly enhance the final plot.

As @eipi10 notes in the comments, these distinctions are somewhat conceptual as the majority of geoms undergo some statistical transformation prior to being plotted. These include `geom_bar`, `geom_smooth`, and `geom_quantile`. Some common exceptions where the data is presented in more or less "raw" form are `geom_point` and `geom_line` and the less commonly used `geom_rug`.

Comment: AFAIK stats and geoms always go together, but every geom has a default stat. So you don't have to explicitly specify a stat, but the stat is still required. If you look at the [ggplot help](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) you can see which stat is the default for each geom. You can also reverse the process and specify a `geom` within a call to `stat_xxx()`. Most of the time you don't have to worry about these details, but it's good to know in case you want to alter the default behavior.

Comment: Probably the most common case where this matters is in `geom_bar` where the default is to count rows (the default stat for `geom_bar` is `stat_count`). Thus, if your data are pre-summarized, you need to specify `stat="identity"`, meaning no transformation of the raw data.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll add a note to hopefully better cover this sentiment.

Comment: the ggplot_help link @eipi10 commented above didn't work for me. I assume this is the intended page https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/, it's certainly helpful for me!

Comment: Glad that helped. It looks like the link in my comment from 4.5 years ago is no longer active. Thanks for posting the current link.

Answer (score 55):

This is only meant to supplement the accepted answer.

According to Hadley Wickkam, the author of ggplot2, in his book 'ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis' [(link here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=XgFkDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=what%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20stat%20and%20geom%20layers%20ggplot2&source=bl&ots=sn54dSeZaW&sig=T9eXzAh-bliVDIshSeTrJkUh5_s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrgcabuJLUAhVJxoMKHScMAJAQ6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20stat%20and%20geom%20layers%20ggplot2&f=false) on p. 91, of section 5.2 'Building a plot layer by layer' :

> You only need to set one of stat and geom: every geom has a default stat, and every stat has a default geom.

The accepted answer above explains well why the two are different. This is meant to explain why they are difficult to distinguish in practice -- whenever you use a geom layer, you are also implicitly using a stat layer (even if it is just the identity transformation); likewise, whenever you use a stat layer, you are also implicitly using a geom layer.

If you are fine with the defaults used by either layer, then it would be redundant to state explicitly both layers. Even if you are not fine with the defaults provided by either layer, you can modify the defaults as parameters to each layer (i.e. you can modify the default geom as a parameter to pass to any `stat_*` function, and you can modify the default stat as a parameter to pass to any `geom_*` function). In the words of Hadley Wickham (same source as above):

> You can pass params in `...` (in which case stat and geom parameters are automatically teased apart)

This is kind of difficult to understand conceptually, which is why I have had this question as well. In his paper about the philosophy underlying ggplot2, [found here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/layered-grammar.pdf), in Section 4, a 'Hierarchy of Defaults', Hadley Wickham explains the practical considerations behind this default behavior in terms of simplifying code which would otherwise unnecessarily long.

For example, without default specifications, and using the grammar of graphics alone, the code for a simple scatter plot might look like:

```
ggplot() +
layer(
data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price),
geom = "point", stat = "identity", position = "identity"
) +
scale_y_continuous() +
scale_x_continuous() +
coord_cartesian()
```

Using defaults for the scales and coordinates, we can write something instead like:

```
ggplot(data = Diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
layer(
geom = "point", stat = "identity", position = "identity"
)
```

But this is *still* annoyingly long of course, since the values of `stat` and `position` are just `"identity"`, which basically means 'do nothing' -- so why have to say that explicitly?

However, the `layer()` function does not have default values for `stat` or `position` -- they need to be specified explicitly in a call to the `layer()` function.

To get around this, Hadley made the `geom_*` functions as well as the `stat_*` functions as [wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) to the `layer()` function which have default values for both the `geom` and `stat` parameter. The difference between the `stat_*` and `geom_*` functions is which parameter has an *immutable* (unchangeable) default value, `stat` or `geom`.

Source: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/layer.html

So for the `geom_*` functions you can change the default value of the `stat` parameter but not the default value of the `geom` parameter, while for the `stat_*` functions you can change the default value of the `geom` parameter but not the default value of the `stat` parameter.

> A layer is a combination of data, stat and geom with a potential position adjustment. Usually layers are created using `geom_*` or `stat_*` calls but it can also be created directly using this function [the `layer()` function].

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that the `stat_*` and `geom_*` functions are in fact wrappers providing sensible defaults to the `layer()` function. To me this was the most eye-opening aspect of your answer. My students will (indirectly) be very grateful to you :-)

Comment: I am strongly convinced that Hadley Wickham creates contorted and confusing designs to force people to buy his books to understand how to use his damn libraries.

Answer (score 1):

geom is for geometrical representation while stat is for statistical infos and representations. i think sometimes geom uses some stats functions such as `stat_count()` used by `geom_bar()`. in this case geom_bar takes one argument (x or y) and the stat_count takes in charge the counting of frequencies.