# R Plot Bar graph transposed dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot the following dataframe as bar plot, where the values for the filteredprovince column are listed on a separate column (n)

Usually, the ggplot and all the other plots works on horizontal dataframe, and after several searches I am not able to find a way to plot this "transposed" version of dataframe.

The cluster should group each bar graph, and within each cluster I would plot each `filteredprovince` based on the value of the `n` column

Thanks you for the support

```
d <- read.table(text=
"  cluster PROVINCIA     n filteredprovince
 1       1 08          765 08              
 2       1 28          665 28              
 3       1 41          440 41              
 4       1 11          437 11              
 5       1 46          276 46              
 6       1 18          229 18              
 7       1 35          181 other           
 8       1 29          170 other           
 9       1 33          165 other           
10       1 38          153 other ", header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the suggestion in comments I almost achived the format desired :

```
ggplot(tab_s, aes(x = cluster, y = n, fill = factor(filteredprovince))) + geom_col()
```

[image]

There is any way to put on Y labels not frequencies but the % ?

Comment: see updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to use the `geom_bar()` geom which gives you problems because it wants to make sort of an histogram but you already have done this kind of summary.

(If you had provided code which you have tried so far I would not have to guess)

In that case you can use `geom_col()` instead.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = filteredprovince, y = n, fill = factor(PROVINCIA))) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can change the default stat of `geom_bar()` from `"count"` to `"identity"`

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = filteredprovince, y = n, fill = factor(PROVINCIA))) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

See [this SO question for what a stat is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775661/what-is-the-difference-between-geoms-and-stats-in-ggplot2)

---

**EDIT:** Update in response to OP's update:

To display percentages, you will have to modify the data itself.

Just divide `n` by the sum of all `n` and multiply by 100.

```
d$percentage <- d$n / sum(d$n) * 100
ggplot(d, aes(x = cluster, y = percentage, fill = factor(filteredprovince))) + geom_col()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I perfectly understand, but if the problem is the orientation of your dataframe, you can transpose it with `t(data)` where `data` is your dataframe.

Comment: Hi. I need to plot only the main province in the dataset for each cluster, so I understand that as the most frequent  filteredprovince (the one with n>200)  will vary between clusters, transposing the dataset will create lot of NaN as some clusters will not have the same  most frequent provinces as the other clusters. There is not way to create a plot of a horizonatal oriented dataframe grouping by cluster?