# Grouped bar plot with frequency numbers in a R function

Tags: r, bar-chart, frequency, geom-text

I want to make a function which would plot a bar chart of a certain variable in a database, grouped by participants' sex. I found a way to do this with a chart that displays proportions:

```
library(ggplot2)
datab <- data.frame(
  value=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5), 50, replace = TRUE),
  value2=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Sex=factor(x=rep(c(1,1,1,0,0),10), labels=c("M","F"))
)


graph_percentages <- function(varijabla){
  ggplot(datab, aes(x= datab[[varijabla]], y=stat(prop), fill=Sex, group=Sex)) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", color= "black") +
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(1), size = 2.3, aes(label= scales::percent(..prop..), y= ..prop..), stat="count", vjust = -0.5)+
    xlab(colnames(datab[,varijabla]))  + ylab(NULL)
}

graph_percentages("value")
```

However, I'm stumped as how to make a similar function that would show frequencies instead of proportions.
The main problem is that in "geom_text" I cannot change the "y=" to display frequencies. At least I have not found how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stat(count)` maybe what you are looking for?

```
ggplot(datab, aes(x= datab[[varijabla]], y=stat(count), fill=Sex, group=Sex)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", color= "black") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(1), size = 2.3, aes(label= ..count.., y= ..count..), stat="count", vjust = -0.5)+
  xlab(colnames(datab[,varijabla]))  + ylab(NULL)
```

And to keep with the updated syntax, you could replace `..count..` with `stat(count)` also in your call to `geom_text()`, i.e:

```
geom_text(position = position_dodge(1), size = 2.3, aes(label= stat(count), y= stat(count)), stat="count", vjust = -0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ..count.. worked perfectly! Is there a list of ..xx.. arguments like ..prop.. and ..count.. somewhere?

Comment: Glad it worked. As I mentioned `..xx..` is the old way to represent `stat(xx)`, as explained by `?stat`. I also like this thread for a more in depth explanaition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226841/7439717